# Implement interface other than from class signature

Tags: java, generics, interface

Let's say, for example, that I wanted to group some classes in a jar library that all fit the definition of my custom interface. Since I can't edit the classes inside the jar in order to implement my interface, is there any other way to use these classes as though they implemented my interface?

Example: I have uneditable classes `A` and `B`. I have a static method in a different class that accepts objects belonging to my interface `I`. How can I pass in `A` and `B` objects without making the method accept all `Object` objects. I want to give `A` and `B` new functionality that **only** they can have.

Comment: Create classes that will implement your interfaces and this classes will serve as wrappers for the third party library classes. This is well known as [Facade Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Comment: @ Luiggi I tried that, but when trying to cast third party objects to my wrapper class, I got a ClassCastException. Could this be a security feature?

Comment: Check my answer. No need to *cast* anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your edit and based on my comment: create a class that will implement your interface I and serve as wrapper for classes A and B. This is [Facade Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). Here's a pretty basic simple example in code:

```
public interface I {
    void methodFromExternalAClass();
    void methodFromExternalBClass();
}

public class MyClass implements I {
    @Override
    public void methodFromExternalAClass() {
         new A().someMethod();
    }
    @Override
    public void methodFromExternalBClass() {
         new B().someMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Adapter` design pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern. Create a wrapper over a class from the library, make the wrapper implement your interface, make wrapper use methods of the class.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to identify whether a given class is in a grouping of classes, similar to using a tagging interface, you could keep a list of `Class` objects and refer to that list to see if a particular class is in your grouping of classes. If that's not what you want than please clarify. I would comment for clarification, but I don't have the reputation.